# How to rewrite function for generic types?

Tags: c#, linq

```
private static Expression<Func<T, bool>> GetExpression<T>(string propertyName, string propertyValue)
        {
            var parametr = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
            var property = Expression.Property(parametr, propertyName);
            var containsMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(string) });

            var objectContains = Expression.Constant(propertyValue, typeof(string));
            var objectEquals   = Expression.Equal(property, Expression.Constant(propertyValue));

            var constrantMethod = Expression.Call(property, containsMethod, objectContains);

            return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(constrantMethod, parametr)
                .Or(Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(objectEquals, parametr));
        }
public static IQueryable<T> ApplyFiltering<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string propertyLabel, string propertyValue)
        {
            var propertyNames = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
                              .Where(e => e.PropertyType == typeof(string))
                              .Where(property => property.Name == propertyLabel)
                              .Select(x => x.Name);

            var predicate = PredicateBuilder.New<T>();

            foreach (var name in propertyNames)
            {
                predicate = predicate.Or(GetExpression<T>(name, propertyValue));
            }

            return source.Where(predicate);
        }
```

I have func for filtering. works fine, but i can't figure out how to use it for each types like for int/decimal not just for string.

Comment: Pass a `Type` variable to replace `typeof(string)`? What's causing problems? What have you tried?

Comment: Just asking - are there cases when `propertyNames` has multiple entries? Or this is some kind of check that property with given name exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your methods are specifically coded to cater for string only. You could make the ApplyFiltering one more generic by adding another generic type for the type of value being used:

```
public static IQueryable<T, TValue> ApplyFiltering<T, TValue>(this IQueryable<T> source, string propertyLabel, TValue propertyValue)
{
    var propertyNames = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
                      .Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(TValue)
                               && p.Name == propertyLabel)
                      .Select(x => x.Name);

    var predicate = PredicateBuilder.New<T>();

    foreach (var name in propertyNames)
    {
        predicate = predicate.Or(GetExpression<T>(name, propertyValue));
    }

    return source.Where(predicate);
}
```

However the GetExpression method specifically calls the Contains method for a string. I don't see how that could be translated for int/decimal.

I would also note that these methods could be the cause of problems down the line as your use of them is not forced to be strongly typed. You would probably be better off calling the Where method directly. The logic in the ApplyFiltering method is strange as you're unlikely (!) to have more than one property with a given name in a class. So getting a number of property names and using a loop is not necessary.

So I would advise this instead of calling ApplyFiltering:

```
source.Where(x => x.MyProperty == "value");
```

Comment: thanks you. i understand you, what i should do. i was trying to replace string with generic type, but stucked with converting from generic to string(forgot to change generic in expression method...)